# How to access index value in a apply/lambda function when index is a PeriodIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, period

When accessing the index value in apply/lambda combination, I use `name` parameter.
But in the case of a period index, it doesn't seem to work.
In below code, I am computing the completion rate at a given row, considering periods of 4 hours.

```
import pandas as pd

p4h = pd.period_range(start='2020-02-01 00:00', end='2020-02-04 00:00', freq='4h')
p1h = pd.period_range(start='2020-02-01 00:00', end='2020-02-04 00:00', freq='1h')

df = p1h.to_series()
p4h_st_as_series = p4h.start_time.to_series()

df['OpenPI'] = df.apply(lambda x:
                   p4h.to_series().loc[p4h_st_as_series.index <=
                             x.start_time].index[-1])

completion = df.apply(lambda row: ((row.name.end_time - row['OpenPI'].start_time)
                          /(row['OpenPI'].end_time - row['OpenPI'].start_time)))
```

Result:

```
>>> AttributeError: 'Period' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Please, does anyone has any idea?

Thanks for your help! Bests,

Comment: isn't `df2` here is a series? so that `row` inside your lambda function is actually the value of a cell. Therefore it doesn't have a name.

Comment: @QuangHoang Hello Quang. Thanks for your reply. I updated the example so that it works on a single DataFrame. I get the same error message: that `Period` object has no `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code below.
I was forgetting the `axis=1` which has been missing.

```
import pandas as pd

p4h = pd.period_range(start='2020-02-01 00:00', end='2020-02-04 00:00', freq='4h', name='p4h')
p1h = pd.period_range(start='2020-02-01 00:00', end='2020-02-04 00:00', freq='1h', name='p1h')

df = p1h.to_frame()
p4h_st_as_series = p4h.start_time.to_series()

df['OpenPI'] = df.apply(lambda x:
               p4h.to_series().loc[p4h_st_as_series.index <=
                         x.name.start_time].index[-1], axis=1)

completion = df.apply(lambda row: ((row.name.end_time - row.OpenPI.start_time)
                      /(row.OpenPI.end_time - row.OpenPI.start_time)), axis=1)
```